# Compare current values of controls with page load values on keypress

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net

I have an aspx page which contains a no. of div with varying no. of controls.
and evey div is visible through a tab menu i.e. on clicking of a tab in menu a div is made visible or false.
Now for my requirement I want to check if a user has made some changes in the foem fields and if it changes any of the field, a message should be displayed showing "Your changes have not been saved".
How can I accompalish this if you could guide me please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
var formChanged = false;

// doc ready
$('#formId').change(function(){
    formChanged = true;
});
```

Comment: It worked for me too once I used the correct selectors - however change needs a blur to trigger.

Comment: Yep, sry for typo error. And yes, it needs a blur that will be triggered lately  when user click on change tab...